# Adding Lists together using Variable Name

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Suppose we have have 100 lists called `list_1`, `list_2`, `..`., `list_100`

If we want to combine these lists, how would we do this? Would something like this work:

```
for i in range(101):
    list_combined += list_{i}
print(list_combined)
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a Matrix (a List of Lists) or join all of the lists together into large list?

Comment: If this was a code review, I would make you go back and replace those 100 individual lists with a single list `all_lists` that contains the lists. Then you just need `list_combined = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_lists))`.

Comment: Your problem lies elsewhere. You should _not_ have 100 similarly called lists. You should have had a list of lists.

Comment: "Suppose we have have 100 lists called list_1, list_2, ..., list_100" **that's your problem**. This should never occur. Instead, you should have used a *container*, like another list or a dict, to hold those lists. Don't try to dynamically use variables. Just re-design your entire approach

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you absolutely *must* have 100 lists as specified in the question, you can do the following:

```
list_combined = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    list_combined += eval(f"list_{i}")
print(list_combined)
```

I strongly discourage this approach in favor of making a list of lists instead, but it will work.

Comment: A must read for everyone who uses `eval`: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: You really, *really* shouldn't encourage this.

Comment: One could use `data += globals()[f'list_{i}']` (or something similar according to the scope) to avoid `eval`.  Technically this answers the question. But the real answer is: Throw away those single variables for the lists and keep them in an appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not how you do it.  Instead you should create a dictionary (or list) called `lists`, and then create `lists[0]`, `lists[1]`, `lists[2]`, etc.  With that, it's trivially easy to iterate through all the lists.

Comment: Couldn't you do this ` list_combined = []
for i in range(52):
    list_combined += 'list_{i}'.format(i) `

Comment: @timeinception23 no, you couldn't. This is **very important** to understand. `list_combined` is a `list` object, `'list_{i}'.format(i)'` **is a `str` object**. Variables **are not strings** and you shouldn't try to treat them as such. Again, you need to fundamentally change the way you are thinking about things. Variables are for source code, they are there for the *programmer*. As a programmer, you should be deciding what *data structures* your code requires. In this case, you should pretty obviously be using a `list`

Answer (score 0):

To combine a list of lists, you could do the following:

```
my_lists = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
]
combined_lists = []
for my_list in my_lists:
    combined_lists += my_list

print(combined_lists)

# which prints
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```